# Updatewithchildren SQLite.net extension do not replace the old element

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I'm using SQLite extension to create a DB. OnetoOne relation and ManytoOne relations work fine, I'm using InsertorReplacewithChildren to manage new and modified elements. But when it comes to OnetoMany relations I have some problems.
Following [SQLite-Net Extensions Manual](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) I have added this in my parent class:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID_child { get; set; }
...
[OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public List<ClinicalTest> ClinicalTests_DB { get; set; }
```

and this in my child class:

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID_clinicaltest { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(typeof(Child))]
    public int ID_child { get; set; }
```

The problem is that if I change some fields of an element in my ClinicalTest and I call either UpdatewithChildren(FatherClassInstance) or InsertorReplacewithChildren(FatherClassInstance) the result is that in the ClinicalTests Table I have two rows: one is the updated element (with the correct foreingkey) and one is the old element (without any foreingkey).
I would have expected just one row with the updated element.
Am I doing something wrong?
Should I clean manually these useless elements?
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, sorry for the trouble.
 
In my code the ID of the clinical test was "lost" during some passages. That was the cause of the problem.